# Compounding difference between these TFSA Savings Account & TFSA GIC interest rates?

Tags: canada, investing, interest-rate, tfsa

From the brochure of my bank, here is an excerpt:

- Interest on the TFSA Savings Account is calculated daily and paid monthly.
- Interest on TFSA GICs is compounded annually and paid at the end of the term.

If GIC is for 1 yr and I am willing to lock the money in for 1 yr, and if both offer same interest rate, is it true that the TFSA will generate a greater P+I at the end of the year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that rates are same, the interest paid monthly would generate greater P+I.

However I doubt in practice if if the TFSA Savings rate would be higher than GIC. Typically more the lockin, more the interest.